# I'm trying to print from a void function, but it won't compile because it says it isn't defined

Tags: c++, function

My code won't compile, but I'm just trying to get my main file to run properly and print the output. I'm also trying to compare if the strings are equal to print. The main errors are in the main file because the header and cpp file compile, but when I try to get some output from the void print function, it crashes and tells me the errors that there's no matching function to call from the parent class. Can you please tell me how to fix this? thank you.

header file:

```
#include <iostream>
#ifndef BOOK_H
#define BOOK_H

class Book
{

    public:

    Book(std::string title, std::string author, int callNo);

    virtual void print();

    virtual bool equals(std::string book1, std::string book2);

    protected:
    
    std::string titleBook;
    std::string auth;
    int number;

};

class Journal: public Book
{

    public:

    Journal(int volume);

    void print();

    protected:

    int vol;

};

#endif
```

cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Book.h"
using namespace std;

Book::Book(string title, string author, int callNo)
{

    titleBook = title;
    auth = author;
    number = callNo;

};

void Book::print() 
{

    titleBook = "   ";
    auth = "    ";
    number = 0;

};

bool Book::equals(string book1, string book2)
{
    
    bool printing = false;

    if(book1 == book2) {
        printing = true;
        cout << "Books are a match!";
        print();
    }
    else if (book2 != book1){
        printing = false;
        cout << "Books are not a match, try again.";
    }

};

Journal::Journal(int volume):Book(titleBook, auth, number)
{

    vol = volume;

};

void Journal::print()
{
    
    vol = 0;

};
```

main file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Book.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    Book b1("Norton’s Star Atlas", "A.P. Norton", 510);
    Book b2("Pocket Sky Atlas", "J. Sinot", 511);

    if (b1.equals(b1, b2)) {

       cout << "The books are the same" << endl;
}

     else {

       cout << "The books are different" << endl;
}

     b1.print();
     b2.print();
    }
    
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: It would help enormously to have the actual error message here

Comment: The equals function you have declared and defined expects two strings. In your main function you're trying to pass in two `Book`s instead. `equals(string, string)` is a totally different function than `equals(Book, Book)`. You need to modify your equals function to take two Book objects, or you need to pass in strings instead.

Comment: Your `print`functions are very badly named. They modify the object and doesn't actually print anything.

Comment: clang is not happy with this `Journal::Journal(int volume):Book(titleBook, auth, number)` you are trying to initialize Book from its own member variables.

Comment: `void Book::print()` is unusual, it does not print but does some unexpected initialization. `bool Book::equals(string book1, string book2)` promised to return a bool but breaks that promise causing undefined behavior.

Comment: *"because the header and cpp file compile"* -- headers should not be compiled. Also, "cpp file" should be better named in your question since the "main file" presumably also has the `.cpp` extension.

Comment: Recommendation: Write less code at a time. Write a few lines. Compile. Test. Don't proceed until the program compiles and all tests pass. If you write everything at once and then compile and test... Well, look at the time you just wasted.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that your method signature and the actual call are different. In the  method signature in the `Book` class, you have the signature written as:

```cpp
virtual bool equals(std::string book1, std::string book2);
```

This tells the compiler that `Book` has a method named `equals` and takes a `std::string` and a `std::string`. But in the main function you call it using two books:

```cpp
Book b1("Norton’s Star Atlas", "A.P. Norton", 510);
Book b2("Pocket Sky Atlas", "J. Sinot", 511);

b1.equals(b1, b2);
```

When the compile tries to find the `equals` method in `Book`, it does not find on which takes two `Book` instances rather than two `std::string` causing it to spit out the `no matching function for call to ‘Book::equals(Book&, Book&)’` message.

You can fix this by adding an `equals` which accepts two `Book` instances. it should not matter whether you replace the existing function or overload  the current one; however, I doubt that you would ever want to compare books by their string value rather than their actual member properties.

Comment: Oh you're absolutely right

Comment: @JohnFilleau I adjusted the answer to better reflect the ussye at hand

Answer (score 2):

Your equal function declared to take two `strings`, but you have provided two `Book` objects.

Assuming you want to compare two titles in your Book, your function looks like this;

```
bool Book::equals(const Book& book1, const Book& book2)
{   

    if(book1.titleBook == book2.titleBook) 
    {
        cout << "Books are a match!";
        return true;
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "Books are not a match, try again.";
        return false;
    }
};
```

Your print functions doesn't make sense;

I have modified your print functions, to print object members;

```
void Book::print() 
{

    std::cout << "titleBook: " << titleBook << '\n'
              << "auth: " << auth << '\n'
              << "number: " << number;

};

void Journal::print()
{
    
    std::cout << "vol: " << vol;

};
```